# Binary tree crashes when compiling

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree, nodes

There seems to be an error when compiling but am not sure what. I've gone through all of it a few times and cannot figure out why.

Also, are there any other things I should do to improve this piece of code in general?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//create structure to hold node
typedef struct node
{
int data;
struct node *left;   //lower no. / points to left node
struct node *right;  //higher no. / points to right node
} node;

void insert(node **rt, int val)     //insertion function
{
node *tmp;

if(*rt == NULL){
    tmp = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));        //allocates memory for node
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        printf(stderr, "Unable to allocate node\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    tmp->data = val;
    *rt = tmp;
}
else{
    if(val > (*rt)->data)
        insert(&(*rt)->right, val);
    else
        insert(&(*rt)->left, val);
}
}

void print_node(node *head)         //starts with head/first node until NULL
{
if(head == NULL)
    return;

if(head->left != NULL)
    print_node(head->left);
    printf("data = %d\n", head->data);

if(head->right != NULL)
    print_node(head->right);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int value[6] = {20,10,5,17,30,21};     //values put into array
int i;                                  //i count
node *head = NULL;
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)              //loop array
    {
        insert(&head, value[i]);
    }

print_node(head);               //recursive search

return 0;
}
```

Comment: When compiling or when running? A compiler crash would be strange. If when running, you should debug to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to miss initialising the `left` and `right` members of a freshly allocated `node`.

To fix this insert after this line

```
    tmp->data = val;
```

the missing initialisation like this:

```
    tmp->left = NULL;
    tmp->right = NULL;
```

---

Also the code misses to print out the right nodes' value.

Answer (score 0):

in this line `printf(stderr, "Unable to allocate node\n");` I think you meant `fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate node\n");`

Comment: It is worrying that the code compiled with that mistake. It suggests an archaic compiler and missing header files.  Having said that, the code has `<stdio.h>` included, so there really isn't an excuse for a compiler not to complain about the abuse of `printf()`, which may mean that the code has been 'sanitized' for presentation on SO.  Ick!

Comment: you're right , he should definitely change compiler . it worked fine after I fixed this "typo".